# How to Make Progress Bar In The Front Webview With Transparant Background?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I want to make transparant background and showing in center layout. But i'm very confused when i'm used `relative layout` my apps crash after showing progress bar and didn't transparant background.

I'm using `android studio` to make a `webview` apps.

This is my code `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar superProgressBar;
    WebView superWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        superProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
        superWebView = findViewById(R.id.mywebView);

        superProgressBar.setMax(100);

        superWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                superProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                superProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
      }
}
```

This is my code `layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.cokein.webviewtest.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/pbc"
            android:progress="25"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where is your transparent WebView?

Comment: have you tried setting background as transparent in the XML

Comment: my progress bar in front of webview. but progress bar have a background. I want to just showing progress bar without background(transparant)

Comment: can you post the screenshot in the question?